# How To Start a Process multiple times for multiple tasks

Tags: c#

The first conversion is successful but when I do the second conversion or call the conversion function a second time, it throws the following exception:

> An Async read operation is already started on the stream ...

How to handle this and use this function for multiple conversions? It works if I close the program and start it again but not when I call it a second time in a single run.

```
private void conversion(string cmd)
{
    try
    {
        p = this.process1;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\ffmpegtool\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();

        if (p.HasExited)
        {
            p.CancelErrorRead();
            p.CancelOutputRead();
            p.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Closed");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception : \n" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better if you can be more specific.
Where in the code did you get the exception?

Comment: How to load file-by-file ... The problem is i convert a file suppose 34.mp4 to 35.mp3 it works fine but when i try to convert another 21.mp4 to 22.mp3 it says "An Async read operation is already started on the stream

Comment: it seems like you doesn't close the streamreader properly. try with a `using` statement

Comment: just replace ..
 p = this.process1;
with 
p = new Process();

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like ffmpeg.exe locks files when reading them, which is why you can't run two instances of it on the same file. If you're going to try and parallelise this, you'll either need to find a different tool that supports it (unlikely) or accept that parallelising this workload is on a file-by-file basis and that's the best you'll get.

Comment: How to load file-by-file  ...
The problem is i convert a file suppose 34.mp4 to 35.mp3 it works fine 
but when i try to convert another 21.mp4 to 22.mp3 it says

"An Async read operation is already started on the stream ..."